# Woocommerce' widget section displays after main content on mobile devices

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar

When I access my woocommerce site via a narrow device, the sidebar falls below the main content. Mobile visitors must scroll all the way down the products to find useful price & category filter widgets.

**My question is, is it possible to somehow put the sidebar above the site content for mobile visitors?**

I tried to modify the archive-product.php file by copying it to my child-theme and moved the sidebar part from the bottom of that file to the top - thinking it would output the html in a different order and solve the issue on narrow screens like so:

```
get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>
```

But it didn't. I researched the web but didn't come up with any other answers so far. Also, I'm pretty new to coding PHP so maybe I'm overlooking real obvious things without realizing it - excuse me if I am.

Anyways, it would be awesome to get a step closer in solving this problem.

Thank you in advance.